# Why can't I crawl the page?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape a table on a website and then convert it into a CSV form. The thing is nothing shows up despite my code. Could you tell me what went wrong?

URL: http://www.multiclick.co.kr/sub/gamepatch/gamerank.html

Don't worry about the language. Please just set the date anytime that is a day or two earlier than today on the calendar and click on the magnifying glass. Then you'll be able to see a table.

```
# Load the required modules
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Open up the page
url = "http://www.multiclick.co.kr/sub/gamepatch/gamerank.html"
web_page = urllib.request.Request(
        url,
        data = None, 
        headers={'User-Agent': ("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) "
                                "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) " 
                                "Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36")})
type(web_page)
web_page = urllib.request.urlopen(web_page)

# Parse the page
soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, "html.parser")
print(soup)

# Get the table
    # Get the columns
    # Get the rows
    # Stack them altogether

# Save it as a csv form
```

Comment: You can't scrape like that a page where content is loaded dynamically. Just fech `http://ws.api.thelog.co.kr/service/info/rank/RRRR-MM-DD` (it's just JSON).

Comment: Or, if you must scrape, you can use Selenium to automate the browser and work through the ajax/dynamic pages

Answer (score 0):

Ais @mx0 said, instead of fetching the mian page, fetch the ajax call, for example:

```
import csv
import requests

link = "http://ws.api.thelog.co.kr/service/info/rank/2018-10-18"

req = requests.get(link)
content = req.json()
with open('ranks.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    # write column titles
    csv_writer.writerow(['gameRank', 'gameName', 'gameTypeName', 'gameShares', 'publisher', 'gameRankUpDown'])
    # write values
    for row in content["list"]:
        csv_writer.writerow(list(row.values()))
```